# ローカル環境開発でのrails sでエラーが発生しました。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ローカル環境開発で `rails s` でエラーが発生しました

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        4: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        3: from /Users/ユーザー名/projects/アプリ名/bin/spring:10:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from /Users/ユーザー名a/projects/アプリ名/bin/spring:10:in `new'
        1: from /Users/ユーザー名/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:95:in `initialize'
/Users/ユーザー名/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version': You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)
```

gemfileです。

```
ruby '2.6.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'faker', '1.9.1'
  gem 'pry-rails' 
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'devise'
gem 'active_hash'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'
gem 'mini_racer'
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
```

"You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile." このエラー文を翻訳したら "このロックファイルでは、Bundler2以降を使用する必要があります。" と出たのでbundle2以降をインストールする必要があるのでしょうか？

以下の手順を実行しましたがうまくいきませんでした。どなたかご教授お願いします。

- `rm -rf Gemfile.lock` で gemfile を一度削除
- `rm -rf vendor/bundle` でアプリにインストールされているgemも削除
- `gem install bundler -v '2.1.4'` で bundle をインストール
- `bundle install` を実行

**実行環境:**

Bundler 2.2.16
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin20]

Comment: `bundle exec rails s`と実行した場合はどうなりますか？

Comment: bundle exec rails sを実行したら無事サーバーが起動しました、なぜでしょう？

Comment: でもrails sを実行したらうまくいきません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*私もちょっと調べ切れていないので、少し憶測が混じっています。*

```
bundle exec rails s
```

のように`bundle exec`付きで実行してください。

`rails`コマンドがgem installしたbundlerではなく、Rubyに標準で付いてきたbundler(`gem list bundler`でdefalutと付いているバージョン)を見に行ってしまうことがあるようです。そのような場合は、新しいbundlerをgemで入れているにもかかわらず、`rails`と単に実行した場合は、その古いバージョンのbundlerを見に行って、バージョン違いを指摘されてしまいます。1->2の場合はえらーですが、2の場合でも、似たような現象として、下記のようなメッセージが出る場合があります。

```
Warning: the running version of Bundler (2.1.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (2.1.4). We suggest you to upgrade to the version that created the lockfile by running `gem install bundler:2.1.4`.
```

解決方法として、`bundle exec`をつけるのは、これは常に最新のbundlerを使った環境で実行しようとします。`rails`はbundlerを自分で探しにいくようになっていますが、他のRuby製アプリ(middleman等)では逆に必要としているものです。ですので、`rails`とせずに`bundle exce rails`とすることで、最新のbundlerを使って、Gemfile.lockの環境のライブラリを使うように動くと言うことです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Comment: @user35049 もしこの回答であなたの問題が解決したのであれば、回答を承認してください。あなた自身にも信用度が加算されバッジの獲得もできます。